# elementary OS won't boot: displays "reboot and select proper boot device"

Tags: release-loki, boot, grub, uefi

I'm installing elementary OS on a Toshiba Satellite l15-b1330 laptop; this laptop was slow with W10 on it, so I opted to format the drive completely and run only elementary OS.

However, the aforementioned message appears upon boot. The bootloader doesn't seem to load?

If I use rEFInd, it'll let me boot into the installed environment. But I don't know how to make it so that I don't need to always boot from rEFInd on a USB.

I appreciate any help in advance, thanks so much!

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: At first, I just got 'reboot and select proper boot device', but I managed to figure it out through some trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out. It seems that the main issue was that GRUB hadn't completely installed.

First, I used the elementary OS live-boot USB that I'd made with Rufus to boot into a live environment. I needed to install boot-repair, which needed a repository added. I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Which allowed me to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

I followed all instructions, made sure to ensure that GRUB was purged, and after reboot, the laptop booted up perfectly!

However, after the first reboot, the problem returned with an additional error message:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

So I booted back into the USB live environment, opened a terminal, and ran

```
sudo bash
cd /boot/efi/EFI
sudo cp -p ubuntu/grubx64.efi Boot
sudo touch ubuntu/grubx64.efi.gbr
```

Now the laptop has no issues when booting. :D